# ResourceMonitorService does not show Load Information

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have standalone cluster 6.5.664.9590 on Windows Server 2019.
In ClusterManifest Enabled ResourceMonitorService

```
<Section Name="ResourceMonitorService">
<Parameter Name="InstanceCount" Value="-1" />
<Parameter Name="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
</Section>
```

Stateless Service run in Win docker container, as ExclusiveProcess.

Link on issue:
https://github.com/microsoft/service-fabric/issues/384

I noticed Warning: "GetResourceUsageAsyncOperation Operation returned SerializationError" and for every containers "Application Service with service Id 0bfceb73-ab70-4f11-9b3d-023249c3ff40 ContainerStatsResponse error SerializationError" in Event Viewer Microsoft-Service Fabric/Admin

Comment: Users are responding to the same issue you posted on GitHub

Answer (score 0):

The SerializationError is because docker change the DateTime format from end with ‘Z’ to end with timezone.

Old: "read": "2015-01-08T22:57:31.547920715Z" still show from docker docs https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#operation/ContainerStats
New: "read": "2019-10-18T17:44:36.5599007-07:00"

They are working out the best way to correct this.